# Check for fields that is dirty and valid

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

In an angular form with pre-populated value, I would want to create an object that is consist of fields that are dirty and valid, that is when user change the holder value and that change is valid. 
I have no problem with simple validation, as I found some examples in the doc, but how can one handle such an object that is conditioned on dirty and valid?

Comment: Please post your code what you did so far to help us to be more concrete

Comment: Since the question is broad, so is my answer. Look at this introduction to form validation before you reinvent any wheels. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxMwW1QBEro

Answer (score 0):

I found good example where we can see validation status:

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/81jgWv?p=preview)**</kbd>

Hope it will help you,

Comment: Thanks Maxim the demo look nice. However at first glance, it seems to be at the view level instead of model level. I am looking at it. On  the other hand I think scope.watch maybe what I needed.

Comment: right, this example has `ng-model="person"`. For sure you can write `$watch`